# Jquery next() and removeClass()

Tags: jquery, html

[image]

if you look in picture aboive. what i want to do is when i click the row, it hides away, the next row become red and click that would hide that away and next becomes available and so on.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.start').unbind("click").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("start");
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().addClass("start");
  });


});
```

```css
.start {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div style="width:500px;" class="siblings">
  <ul>
    <li class="start"> 1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The first row hide away fine on click. The class "start" gets added to next row. But clicking on that does not work.

How I can remove the red row by clicking and next becomes available.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Because DOM knows nothing about new elements with class `.start`

Answer (score 1):

Use a [delegate](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```js
$('div.siblings ul').on('click','li.start',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('start').hide().next().addClass('start');
});
```

```css
.start {
    color:red;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;" class="siblings">
 <ul>
   <li class="start"> 1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
</ul>   
</div>
```